# Having trouble using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm having trouble serializing an immutable instance with the DataContractSerializer, since the properties on the class I'm serializing is missing setters. The problem is that I only want to serialize the instance (just so it can be written to a log), and I will **never** need to deserialize it. Is there a way to bypass this behavior?

The class I'm trying to serialize:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    private readonly string _name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

The code used for serializing the class:

```
public string Serialize()
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder)) {
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, this);
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the `[DataMember]` on the fields thus allowing you to have property getters. These fields can still be private. However it cannot be `readonly` as it needs to construct the object then set the fields.

[Edit]
This will cause the field names to be used unless you use `[DataMember(Name = "Name1")]`

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have thought of this before posting the question. :)

Comment: don't know if this changed but in .net 4.5.1 you can serialize and deserialize readonly fields

Answer (score 3):

This version uses the ISerializable attribute instead of [DataContract].
I don't know how this will affect operability, but does not need a public setter.

```
[Serializable]
public class Person : ISerializable
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
        System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        using (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, this);
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Name", _name);
    }
}
```